# Spring annation for service

Tags: spring

I am trying to use Spring annotation to define controller, service and dao, but failed.

the error message is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.abs.absbase.ABSService] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.abs.absbase.ABSService]: expected at least 1 matching bean
```

but I do define the service.

Another question is, how to define a sessionfactory to overwrite the HibernateDaoSupport in the ABSDaoImpl ?

Thanks

Source code is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/abs.do")
public class ABSController {    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ABSService")
    ABSService service; 
    ...
}

@Service(value="ABSService") 
public class ABSServiceImpl implements ABSService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ABSDao")
    ABSDao dao;
}

@Repository(value="ABSDao") 
public class ABSDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ABSDao {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me you just need to remove the **@Qualifier** annotation you have defined above the declaration of ABSService object in the controller. And also remove the **(value="ABSService")** from the @Service annotation on the service.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.